# Is there a method to short-circuit a function on Err like SQL's ifnull or coalesce?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return an `Err` when any step of initialization returns an `Err`:

```
fn init<'r>(&self) -> Result<(), ()> {
    match self.check_1() {
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
        _ => {}
    };
    match self.check_2() {
        Err(e) => return Err(e),
        _ => {}
    };
    // [more checks]
    return Ok(());
}
```

To me, this is cluttered.  SQL has [`ifnull`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-ifnull/) or [`coalesce`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-coalesce/) which returns the first non-null result.  As can be seen, I'm trying to do that, but return the first `Err`.

Is there any syntax or macro that will enable me to return the first `Err` encountered, while not executing subsequent check functions, i.e. short-circuiting the check evaluation logic?

Comment: Consider re-reading *The Rust Programming Language* — [Recoverable Errors with Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)

Comment: See also the `if let` syntax. For maximum idiomatic usage, remove the explicit `return` keyword.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster for the ridiculously fast response.  I really appreciate your attention to this question.  Please consider marking as duplicate because this question is a reasonable artifact to point people to a the question mark operator.  I spent 20 minutes asking google questions along these lines and there aren't great results coming from this SQL ifnull mental model.  I don't care about the points or whatever, but the artifact may be useful to others.  Or don't.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Applying the question mark — `fn init(&self) -> Result<(), ()> { self.check_1()?; self.check_2()?; Ok(()) }`.

Comment: Yup.  That makes sense.

Comment: @Shepmaster . Can I ask you another stupid question?  Can I return the contained value of an `Err` if a function returns an `Err` without a `match` ? Is there something more idiomatic than `match self.init() { Err(e) => return e,  _ => {} }`

Comment: You want to return the error value, but no longer wrapped in a `Result`? That's not typical, no. As mentioned earlier, I'd use an `if let`, but otherwise nothing is coming to mind.

Comment: `if let`.  That would be better.